# Add Form & HTML to Lightbox.prototype in lightbox.js

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, lightbox, colorbox

I have need to build a code just like Facebook does for pictures. Im talking about the "pop" or Lightbox they use so in the right side you can comment, in this case I would send an e+mail, and insert a random image on the bottom.

I was also thinking in colorbox, but I use a inline html and if the user want to go from previous to next pictures I will be very lost as I dont know how to do this in Colorbox (including a form and not just images),

Anyway the contact form is the same for all pictures. Each user will have 8 pictures and 1 contact form, thats already done. I need to make or build a Lightbox like the one used by Facebook.

Thats why I found inside the lightbox.js (my other option) the part where the HTML forms it self here:

```
 Lightbox.prototype.build = function() {
      var $lightbox,
        _this = this;
      $("<div>", {
        id: 'lightboxOverlay'
      }).after($('<div/>', {
        id: 'lightbox'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-outerContainer'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-container'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        "class": 'lb-image'
      }), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-nav'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-prev'
      }), $('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-next'
      })), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-loader'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-cancel'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        src: this.options.fileLoadingImage
      }))))), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-dataContainer'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-data'
      }).append($('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-details'
      }).append($('<span/>', {
        "class": 'lb-caption'
      }), $('<span/>', {
        "class": 'lb-number'
      })), $('<div/>', {
        "class": 'lb-closeContainer'
      }).append($('<a/>', {
        "class": 'lb-close'
      }).append($('<img/>', {
        src: this.options.fileCloseImage
      }))))))).appendTo($('body'));
      $('#lightboxOverlay').hide().on('click', function(e) {
        _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox = $('#lightbox');
      $lightbox.hide().on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-outerContainer').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).attr('id') === 'lightbox') _this.end();
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-prev').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex - 1);
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-next').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.changeImage(_this.currentImageIndex + 1);
        return false;
      });
      $lightbox.find('.lb-loader, .lb-close').on('click', function(e) {
        _this.end();
        return false;
      });
    };
```

My question is, can I insert the form in HTML? I guess I can.
But can I use PHP include maybe to insert functions for the random image etc?

What will you use to achieve something like that? Do you know an example I can use as reference? I have really read documentation and a lot of stuff for the main stuff like Colorbox and Lightbox, also it has to be compatible with Jquery.

EDIT : WOOOOW!! : Look what i found under jquerytools. http://jquerytools.org/demos/combine/html5-form/index.html

If this is compatible on internet explorer 6 and beyond, I have a winner.

Comment: If your Lightbox file(s) are PHP-based, I'd say `why not->?`, and give it a whirl!

Comment: I have no much time to finish this an other tasks, this is why i need to go in the right direction before starting, But be sure i will test it .. Im worried about the javacript not working properly forming PHP

Comment: Hey take a look at this http://jquerytools.org/demos/combine/html5-form/index.html